# How to fix "Cannot use import statement outside a module" when running karma unit test with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

RecordsControllerTest.spec.js

```
 // import RecordsController from '../../public/RecordsController';
import {app} from '../../public/app.js';    // without this gives "Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. "


describe('RecordsController', function() {
     //beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

    var $controller, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    describe('$scope.grade', function() {
        it('sets the strength', function() {
            var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            /*var controller =*/ $controller('RecordsController', { $scope: $scope });

            let grade = $scope.grade(1);
            expect(grade).toEqual('small');
        });
    });
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-phonecat",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A tutorial application for AngularJS",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.7.x",
    "angular-animate": "1.7.x",
    "angular-resource": "1.7.x",
    "angular-route": "1.7.x",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.x",
    "jquery": "3.3.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.7.x",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "karma": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run copy-libs",
    "update-deps": "npm update",
    "postupdate-deps": "npm run copy-libs",
    "copy-libs": "cpx \"node_modules/{angular,angular-*,bootstrap/dist,jquery/dist}/**/*\" app/lib -C",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "npm test -- --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
});

export {app};
```

karma.conf.js

```
//jshint strict: false
// there are more things than needed, could clean up. Same in package.json
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: './app',

        files: [
            'lib/angular/angular.js',
            'lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            'lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'lib/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '**/*.module.js',
            '*!(.module|.spec).js',
            '!(lib)/**/*!(.module|.spec).js',
            '**/*.spec.js',
            '../public/*.js',    // works with this because gets real files probably which we test
        ],

        autoWatch: true,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine'
        ]

    });
};
```

RecordsController.js

```
/*var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
});*/

import {app} from './app.js';

app.controller('RecordsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.submit = function () {
        console.log($scope);
        $http.post( app.baseUrl + 'save', {name: $scope.name, price: $scope.price})
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.records.push(response.data)
            });
    }

    $http.get(app.baseUrl + 'list')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.records = response.data;
        });


    $scope.grade = function(price) {
        if (price > 100) {
            return 'big';
        } else if (price > 50) {
            return 'medium';
        } else {
            return 'small';
        }
    };
}]);

//export {app};
```

Application works. If I do not have app.js file but define app in same file as RecordsController.js - unit test works. But when I moved code to app.js - test stops working. Here is output:

```
npm test -- --single-run

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 pretest /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> npm install


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> npm run copy-libs


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 copy-libs /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> cpx "node_modules/{angular,angular-*,bootstrap/dist,jquery/dist}/**/*" app/lib -C

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 534 packages in 2.942s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 10 vulnerabilities (6 low, 3 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 test /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> karma start karma.conf.js "--single-run"

27 12 2020 07:58:51.305:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.module.js" does not match any file.
27 12 2020 07:58:51.307:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/*!(.module|.spec).js" does not match any file.
27 12 2020 07:58:51.313:WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.spec.js" were excluded or matched by prior matchers.
27 12 2020 07:58:51.325:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
27 12 2020 07:58:51.326:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
27 12 2020 07:58:51.329:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
27 12 2020 07:58:51.773:INFO [Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket M3VJxSZLyXP8VAmmAAAA with id 36635738
Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR: 'DEPRECATION:', 'Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Jasmine, please use the specFilter option in `configure`'

Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nSyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module\nSyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nSyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module\nSyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"
  }
Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.002 secs / 0 secs)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Or can you  recommend tutorial where there is example of unit test where files are imported?

**Update**

karma.conf.js afeter @tmhao2005 answer:

```
//jshint strict: false
// there are more things than needed, could clean up. Same in package.json
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: './app',

        files: [
            'lib/angular/angular.js',
            'lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            'lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'lib/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '**/*.module.js',
            '*!(.module|.spec).js',
            '!(lib)/**/*!(.module|.spec).js',
            '**/*.spec.js',
            '../public/*.js',    // works with this because gets real files probably which we test
        ],

        autoWatch: true,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-webpack',
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            // process your `esmodule` syntax of your files
            '../public/*.js': ['webpack'],
            '**/*.spec.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: {
            // karma watches the test entry points
            // (you don't need to specify the entry option)
            // webpack watches dependencies
            // webpack configuration
        },


    });
};
```

And now getting

```
npm test -- --single-run

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 pretest /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> npm install


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> npm run copy-libs


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 copy-libs /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> cpx "node_modules/{angular,angular-*,bootstrap/dist,jquery/dist}/**/*" app/lib -C

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 786 packages in 3.663s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 10 vulnerabilities (6 low, 3 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 test /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> karma start karma.conf.js "--single-run"

30 12 2020 17:50:53.375:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.module.js" does not match any file.
30 12 2020 17:50:53.377:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/*!(.module|.spec).js" does not match any file.
30 12 2020 17:50:53.384:WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.spec.js" were excluded or matched by prior matchers.
⚠ ｢wdm｣: Hash: d4e94cf661365475ea55
Version: webpack 4.41.1
Time: 57ms
Built at: 2020-12-30 17:50:53

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
30 12 2020 17:50:53.408:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.module.js" does not match any file.
30 12 2020 17:50:53.409:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/*!(.module|.spec).js" does not match any file.
30 12 2020 17:50:53.417:WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.spec.js" were excluded or matched by prior matchers.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
⚠ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 4b332cf791759062b309
Version: webpack 4.41.1
Time: 18ms
Built at: 2020-12-30 17:50:53
                              Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
     ../public/RecordsController.js  1.48 KiB    1, 2  [emitted]  ../public/RecordsController
                   ../public/app.js  1.11 KiB       2  [emitted]  ../public/app
Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec.js  1.45 KiB    0, 2  [emitted]  Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec
Entrypoint Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec = Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec.js
Entrypoint ../public/app = ../public/app.js
Entrypoint ../public/RecordsController = ../public/RecordsController.js
[0] ./public/app.js 227 bytes {0} {1} {2} [built]
[1] ./app/Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec.js 952 bytes {0} [built]
[2] ./public/RecordsController.js 957 bytes {1} [built]

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
30 12 2020 17:50:53.568:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
30 12 2020 17:50:53.568:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
30 12 2020 17:50:53.573:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
30 12 2020 17:50:53.969:INFO [Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket xExD5D27bFhOOfMsAAAA with id 98015757
Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR: 'DEPRECATION:', 'Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Jasmine, please use the specFilter option in `configure`'

Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0) RecordsController $scope.grade sets the strength FAILED
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
    
    https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20e%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.9%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3De%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A138%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A4926%3A19%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A5086%3A32)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20injectionArgs%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A5111%3A58)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A5135%3A18)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A5032%3A35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A5042%3A11%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A387%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A5022%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.createInjector%20%5Bas%20injector%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F59efdd7db87c914e8c987ccc770455b4feb59f8f%3A4939%3A19)
        at <Jasmine>
        at lib/angular/angular.js:138:12
        at lib/angular/angular.js:5062:15
        at forEach (lib/angular/angular.js:387:20)
        at loadModules (lib/angular/angular.js:5022:5)
        at Object.createInjector [as injector] (lib/angular/angular.js:4939:19)
        at UserContext.WorkFn (/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3449:52)
        at <Jasmine>
    TypeError: Cannot read property '$new' of undefined
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec.js:1:1385)
        at <Jasmine>
Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.002 secs / 0.008 secs)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

**Update 2**

Added $interpolateProvider as dependency, app.js now:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';

app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
}]);

export {app};
```

Added development mode, karma.conf.js now:

```
//jshint strict: false
// there are more things than needed, could clean up. Same in package.json
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: './app',

        files: [
            'lib/angular/angular.js',
            'lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            'lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'lib/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '**/*.module.js',
            '*!(.module|.spec).js',
            '!(lib)/**/*!(.module|.spec).js',
            '**/*.spec.js',
            '../public/*.js',    // works with this because gets real files probably which we test
        ],

        autoWatch: true,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-webpack',
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            // process your `esmodule` syntax of your files
            '../public/*.js': ['webpack'],
            '**/*.spec.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: {
            // karma watches the test entry points
            // (you don't need to specify the entry option)
            // webpack watches dependencies
            // webpack configuration.
            // dev mode for tests to work
            "mode": "development",
        },
    });
};
```

Now getting error:

```
darius@darius-Vostro-5481:~/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker$ npm test -- --single-run

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 pretest /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> npm install


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> npm run copy-libs


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 copy-libs /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> cpx "node_modules/{angular,angular-*,bootstrap/dist,jquery/dist}/**/*" app/lib -C

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 786 packages in 3.714s

11 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 10 vulnerabilities (6 low, 3 moderate, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 test /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker
> karma start karma.conf.js "--single-run"

05 01 2021 17:03:25.368:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.module.js" does not match any file.
05 01 2021 17:03:25.370:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/*!(.module|.spec).js" does not match any file.
05 01 2021 17:03:25.376:WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.spec.js" were excluded or matched by prior matchers.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 3879665b411e2fff46cc
Version: webpack 4.41.1
Time: 53ms
Built at: 2021-01-05 17:03:25
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
05 01 2021 17:03:25.396:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.module.js" does not match any file.
05 01 2021 17:03:25.397:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/*!(.module|.spec).js" does not match any file.
05 01 2021 17:03:25.402:WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/app/**/*.spec.js" were excluded or matched by prior matchers.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: bfe70362116b7e4fdf82
Version: webpack 4.41.1
Time: 18ms
Built at: 2021-01-05 17:03:25
                              Asset      Size                            Chunks             Chunk Names
     ../public/RecordsController.js  5.83 KiB       ../public/RecordsController  [emitted]  ../public/RecordsController
                   ../public/app.js  4.23 KiB                     ../public/app  [emitted]  ../public/app
Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec.js  5.77 KiB  Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec  [emitted]  Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec
Entrypoint ../public/app = ../public/app.js
Entrypoint Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec = Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec.js
Entrypoint ../public/RecordsController = ../public/RecordsController.js
[./app/Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec.js] 954 bytes {Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec} [built]
[./public/RecordsController.js] 958 bytes {../public/RecordsController} [built]
[./public/app.js] 253 bytes {../public/app} {Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec} {../public/RecordsController} [built]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
05 01 2021 17:03:25.502:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
05 01 2021 17:03:25.503:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
05 01 2021 17:03:25.507:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
05 01 2021 17:03:25.963:INFO [Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket t4Hc0-IijbJd_27rAAAA with id 24424610
Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR: 'DEPRECATION:', 'Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Jasmine, please use the specFilter option in `configure`'

Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0) RecordsController $scope.grade sets the strength FAILED
    Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'RecordsController' is not registered.
    https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.9/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=RecordsController
        at lib/angular/angular.js:138:12
        at $controller (lib/angular/angular.js:11680:17)
        at /home/darius/Private/Projects/learning/symfony_angular_docker/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2555:14
        at UserContext.eval (webpack:///./app/Tests/RecordsControllerTest.spec.js?:22:34)
        at <Jasmine>
Chrome 87.0.4280 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.005 secs / 0.01 secs)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

**Update 3:**

I am thinking - maybe it does not see the controller because it imports app.js without controller? And controller is assigned in another file to the app. But test just does not see that another file. Maybe I need to export somehow controller from RecordsController.js file? And import it in the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much time finnaly with the help of tmhao2005 answer found a working solution:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';

app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
}]);

export {app};
```

single_page.html.twig

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.9/angular.js"></script>
    {#    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>#}

    <script type="module" src="RecordsController.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" >
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="RecordsController">
            <h1>Records controller</h1> <br>

            <div class="row col-md-4">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name" id="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Price</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="price" id="price">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>


            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>

                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="(key, record) in records">
                    <td>// record.id //</td>
                    <td>// record.name //</td>
                    <td>// record.price //</td>
                    <td>// grade(record.price) //</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <a-great-eye></a-great-eye>
        </div> <!-- end records controller -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

RecordsControllerTest.spec.js

```
import {RecordsController} from '../../public/RecordsController.js';

describe('RecordsController', function() {
    var $controller, $rootScope, $http;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$http_){
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $http = _$http_;
    }));

    describe('$scope.grade', function() {
        it('sets the strength', function() {
            var $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            var controller = new RecordsController($scope, $http);

            let grade = $scope.grade(1);
            expect(grade).toEqual('small');
        });
    });
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-phonecat",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A tutorial application for AngularJS",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.7.x",
    "angular-animate": "1.7.x",
    "angular-resource": "1.7.x",
    "angular-route": "1.7.x",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.x",
    "jquery": "3.3.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.7.x",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "karma": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^4.0.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run copy-libs",
    "update-deps": "npm update",
    "postupdate-deps": "npm run copy-libs",
    "copy-libs": "cpx \"node_modules/{angular,angular-*,bootstrap/dist,jquery/dist}/**/*\" app/lib -C",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "npm test -- --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js"
  }
}
```

RecordsController.js

```
import {app} from './app.js';

function RecordsController($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.submit = function () {
        console.log($scope);
        $http.post( app.baseUrl + 'save', {name: $scope.name, price: $scope.price})
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.records.push(response.data)
            });
    }

    $http.get(app.baseUrl + 'list')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.records = response.data;
        });


    $scope.grade = function(price) {
        if (price > 100) {
            return 'big';
        } else if (price > 50) {
            return 'medium';
        } else {
            return 'small';
        }
    };
}

app.controller('RecordsController', RecordsController);

export {RecordsController};
```

karma.conf.js

```
//jshint strict: false
// there are more things than needed, could clean up. Same in package.json
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: './app',

        files: [
            'lib/angular/angular.js',
            'lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            'lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'lib/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '**/*.module.js',
            '*!(.module|.spec).js',
            '!(lib)/**/*!(.module|.spec).js',
            '**/*.spec.js',
            '../public/*.js',    // works with this because gets real files probably which we test
        ],

        autoWatch: true,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-webpack',
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            // process your `esmodule` syntax of your files
            '../public/*.js': ['webpack'],
            '**/*.spec.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: {
            // karma watches the test entry points
            // (you don't need to specify the entry option)
            // webpack watches dependencies
            // webpack configuration.
            // dev mode for tests to work
            "mode": "development",
        },
    });
};
```

So really last problem was that test was importing app.js but in app.js file the controller was not assingned to app. It was assigned in different file. But I was not able to make test know about this. But different solution was to make RecordsController as seperate function. Then there is no need to even mock app.

I am just not sure if

```
app.controller('RecordsController', RecordsController);
```

is good to have in RecordsController file, from architecture point of view.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing code in code from `es6` (also aka `esnext`) module so it won't work properly without configuring more things.

But you can also use `karma-webpack` to transform your code to be able run against browsers. Here are a few things you should do to add it:

- Install needed packages:

```sh
npm i -D webpack karma-webpack webpack@4.41.1 
// looks like `webpack5` doesn't work with `karma-webpack`
```

- Configure your `karma.conf.js` to use `karma-webpack`:

```js
preprocessors: {
  // process your `esmodule` syntax of your files
  '../public/*.js': ['webpack'],
  '**/*.spec.js': ['webpack']
},
webpack: {
  // karma watches the test entry points
  // (you don't need to specify the entry option)
  // webpack watches dependencies
  // webpack configuration
  "mode": "development",
},
plugins: [
   // ...
  'karma-webpack',
],
```

Comment: Now getting Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
 
Tried various ways to solve it but so far cannot find one. Updated the post. Not sure if that should be marked as solved and new question created or not.

Comment: Looks like you esm code has been transformed properly now. Can you set this `$interpolateProvider` as array dependency as well?

Comment: You can make it work by setting back to development mode in `webpack` configuration to prevent renaming your vars causing issue (but you should always do array dependency to make it work in case of production). But in case of test, we should go for `development` mode. Check my updated answer again where `{ webpack: { mode": "development" }}`

Comment: Still not able to make it work, updated question with new error.

Comment: The message is saying your code has been transpiled back to es5 (be able to run against browser). The error is about your logic of your code (looks like a controller named `RecordsController ` yet registered)

Comment: so that is good that is transpiled to es5? I am surprised if today browser needs still to transpile it to run. But I do not understand "(looks like a controller named RecordsController  yet registered)" what do you mean? I do not see what is wrong with my logic in that controller.